# Would darkness cast at 4th level be dispelled by Daylight?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Would a *darkness* cast at 4th level be dispelled by *daylight*?

The text suggests that the spell must be of higher than 3rd level, but I am unsure.

> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of darkness created by a spell of 3rd level or lower, the spell that created the darkness is dispelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

Daylight only dispels darkness of 3rd level or lower. It has no effect on darkness at a higher level than that.

[Jeremy Crawford](https://t.co/R1pvnQwOUz) has agreed on a similar case (though with reversed logic):

> See the final paragraph of the darkness spell for what it does to a light spell of 2nd level or lower. If a source of magical light is not a spell of 2nd level or lower, darkness can be illuminated by that light.

The spells will only dispel each other at or below the level specified in the spells' description.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; it flipped it. The question asks whether Sunlight dispels darkness in which case the answer is yes, a 4th level darkness cannot be dispelled by Sunlight,

Comment: darkness prevails over light spells of the same level?